# Delete all fields where timestamp occured 24 or more hours ago

Tags: mysql

This is supposed to delete all players that was deleted more than 24 hours ago. But this deleted my whole players table. Luckily I made a backup before testing tho so no harm. What Am I doing wrong?

`deleted` is `Int(10) unsigned default 0` and php's `time()` is used to store the time.

```
DELETE FROM players WHERE deleted < (unix_timestamp(now()) - 86400000)
```

Answer (score 0):

One (most obvious) problem is that the MySQL `unix_timestamp` function returns number of seconds since the beginning of the epoch, not milliseconds.

There's only 86,400 seconds in 24 hours. The literal you have represents 1000 days.

My approach would be do the date arithmetic on the DATETIME, and then convert that result.

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR )
```

---

NOTES:

you could test the predicates (i.e. the WHERE clause) in a SELECT statement, rather than a DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

24 hours of seconds is 24*60*60 = 86400

Linux time is seconds since epoch so if this is the value stored in the deleted int(10) column then then the statement should be:

DELETE FROM players WHERE deleted < (unix_timestamp(now()) - 86400)